# Academic position in the UK, do universities in the UK pay for dependent tuition?

Tags: united-kingdom, tuition

I'm an assistant professor in the US and I would like to move to the UK. My daughter will be starting college this September and I was wondering if universities in the UK offer any tuition waivers if my daughter enrolls in the same university? and which universities in the UK would offer something like this.

Update: it's worth mentioning that my daughter and I are US citizens. we don't hold any UK or EU citizenships.

Comment: I have never heard of this practice in the UK and I very much doubt that any UK university would do this -- it risks accusations of corruption. In the UK, tuition fees are paid directly to the university by the government (via the government-owned Student Loans Company), meaning that the student never handles the money themselves. For these reasons, I think it would be extremely difficult, or in fact impossible, to negotiate such a fee waiver.

Comment: Like @astronat I have never heard of this happening in the UK. It is not offered at my current institution as far as I am aware, I did look.

Comment: The obvious place to look would be the handful of private universities, but I'm not finding anything relevant on their websites.

Comment: @astronat as an international student, I don't think they would qualify for loans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am an American and was an assistant professor in a UK university. They laughed at me in the polite British way for being a stupid Yank when I asked about benefits like this. With the single pay spine and the craziness of British tax law, they wouldn't even know how to do it in a formal way.

If your daughter attended your *school* (department in US speak), they could probably work with you to wave the international fees and only charge you home fees (9k a year), but with Brexit looming, you cannot really count on any future promises (or even a guarantee that she would legally be allowed to attend a university).

Comment: Good summary. Welcome in Britain.

Comment: The school would not have any discretion on the fees charged. The fees are set by national regulations (see [here](https://www.ukcisa.org.uk/Information--Advice/Fees-and-Money/England-fee-status#layer-6082) for England). The university must have proof that these regulations are met in case of a government audit. As you know immigration is a sensitive topic here at the minute, so I don't think a university would take a risk on this for a student who almost certainly doesn't meet home requirements. Of course a private institution could charge whatever they want.

Comment: @mg4w there are of course scholarships and other pots of money that can be misdirected.

Comment: @StrongBad, yes,  but that isn't changing the fee status of a student (which is a legal matter). At any rate I think this sort of thing would be a very hard sell to the other faculty as they would surely want the same for their dependants. So unless it is offered to all I don't think it would happen.